# Syntax for Turtle Interaction on Same Patch?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to create a basic victimization model in netlogo. In this model, there will be two agents, one an offender and another a victim. The victims have a state variable to represent their memory, with a total memory of 5. I want to program it so that if the victims are on the same patch as an offender, they will lose -1 memory, but if they are not on the same patch, it will do nothing.

I have programmed all the movements, but do not know how to program this interaction between the agents

Answer (score 0):

The primitive `turtles-here` can allow one turtle to check all other turtles on the same patch. This can for example be used to have a turtle do something based on a condition

```
`if any? turtles-here with[<condition>][<do something>]`
```

or to have a turtle direct other turtles on the same patch to do something

```
ask turtles-here[<do something>]
```